Inertia <Head> component in Laravel adds "- Laravel" suffix to title
I'm using Laravel Inertia with React for the frontend of my application. When I use the <Head> component of Inertia to set the title in my React components, it automatically appends "-Laravel" to the end of the title.
<Head>
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A detailed description of My Page." />
</Head>

Issue:
Despite setting the title as "This is the title" using the <Head> component of Inertia, the title of the page is displayed as "This is the title - Laravel".
Additional Information:

I'm using Laravel Inertia with React for the frontend.
Is there a way to prevent the "-Laravel" suffix from being added to the title when using the <Head> component in Inertia?


You should check "/resources/js/app.jsx" file.
Initially the config is:
const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel'; which takes the VITE_APP_NAME value from .env file.
In your case maybe did not find it in .env file and by default is "Laravel"

You can control this config with title callback based on the documentation.
I guess you have an implementation in the /resources/js/app.jsx or tsx file similar to the one below.
const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';
createInertiaApp({
  title: title => `${title} - ${appName}`,
  // ...
})

The above-shared appName is added automatically. So, to achieve your goal, just update your implementation to look like the below snippet.
createInertiaApp({
  title: title => `${title}`,
  // ...
})


